# Debugging code in the Python interpreter

Tags: python, debugging, function, interpreter, functional-testing

I like testing functions in the *Python interpreter*. Is it possible to debug a function in the *Python interpreter* when I want to see more than a return value and a side effect?

If so, could you show basic debugger operations (**launching the function with arguments, setting breakpoint, next step, step into, watching variable**)? If not, how would you debug a function another way?

The point is, I want to debug only a particular function which will be supplied with arguments. I don't want to debug whole module code.

thank you for advice

Comment: Have you searched for `pdb` with Google?

Comment: @hochl I thought that pdb is an application (something like gdb for C language) and I didn't know that it's a module. I will try it, if it's able to debug particular function.

Comment: It is -- `pdb` is the way to go, read the [module description](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to debug specific function you can using this -

```
>>> import pdb
>>> import yourmodule
>>> pdb.run('yourmodule.foo()')
```

over the command line. `pdb.set_trace()` should be added in your function to break there.

More info on pdb can be seen here - http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html

Comment: Can I find out the line numbers where should I set a break point in the interpreter or should I find out it from the editor?

Comment: OK, now I understand. I should place `pdb.set_trace()` in my source code. Nice job, thanks. I haven't understood it before.

Answer (score 7):

See pdb module. Insert into code:

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

... makes a breakpoint.

Answer (score 5):

The code-to-debug does not need to be modified to include `pdb.set_trace()`. That call can be made directly in the interpreter just before the code-to-debug:

```
>>> import pdb
>>> pdb.set_trace(); <code-to-debug>
```

For example, given `test_script.py` with the following code:

```
def some_func(text):
    print 'Given text is {}'.format(repr(text))
    for index,char in enumerate(text):
        print ' '*index, char
```

an interpreter session to debug `some_func` using the debugger commands step-into (`s`), next (`n`) and continue (`c`) would look like:

```
>>> import pdb
>>> import test_script
>>> pdb.set_trace(); test_script.some_func('hello')
--Call--
> c:\src\test_script.py(1)some_func()
-> def some_func(text):
(Pdb) s
> c:\src\test_script.py(2)some_func()
-> print 'Given text is {}'.format(repr(text))
(Pdb) n
Given text is 'hello'
> c:\src\test_script.py(3)some_func()
-> for index,char in enumerate(text):
(Pdb) c
 h
  e
   l
    l
     o
>>>
```

See the docs for the `pdb` module for more information on how to use the debugger: http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html

Additionally, while using the debugger, the `help` command provides a nice list of commands and `help <command>` gives help specific to the given command.

Comment: Aha nice, the code I need to step through requires a lot of setup, so the accepted answer ends up being a huge pain - this works very nicely though.